# Loop Selected Shapes

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2015, foreach, vsto

I need to Loop through the selected shapes on the worksheet. I need it to look something like this:

```
    Dim VmyApp As Excel.Application = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application
    Dim VmySel As Excel.ShapeRange = TryCast(VmyApp.Selection, Excel.ShapeRange)

    For Each VmyShape In VmySel
    ...
    Next
```

Thank you so much in advance..

Answer (score 1):

To loop though only the selected shapes, you can use the below loop

```
For Each VmyShape In Selection.ShapeRange
...
Next
```

and if you want to loop through all shapes, then the below loop

```
For Each VmyShape In ActiveSheet.Shapes
...
Next
```

Comment: Thnx for the responsei am trying to do so, i actually did it like that in Excel VBA but when i try to type selection in VS2015 i don't get it in the intellisense list

Comment: intelllisense may not work, if corresponding module is not present. but is this working for you?

Comment: no unfortunately its not, i may have missed declaring something or missed a reference "Import"

Comment: You may need to include Microsoft Office 15.0 Object library in your macro reference.

Comment: its included and many more references. I still can't get to refer to the selection as a shape range and then refer to each item/shape in the shaperange collection to loop through

Comment: I am using VisualStudio 2015 by the way

Comment: Please check whether Microsoft Excel 15.0 Object library is also included? if this still doesn't work, whats the error message you are getting?